Action movie where the guy fights like a scorpion
It's an old movie, 1990's or earlier but I am not sure. It may be a Chinese movie.
So here is this simple guy who learns fighting by drawing a sketch of another guy's (bad guy) fighting techniques. The bad guy fights like a scorpion, meaning he bends like a scorpion and uses one leg as scorpion tail. The bad guy works for a bad group and protects his boss and obeys orders. I think half of the the bad guy's face is covered by his hair. In the climax both the good and the bad guy fight like scorpions. 
Any idea what the name of that movie was?

Um, how does one fight like a scorpion actually?

@NapoleonWilson  using the tail :) .. That fight is awesome...

@NapoleonWilson they both just bend like scorpion and using 1 leg as scorpion tail..

@NapoleonWilson there's literally a scorpion style https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9vF8C_QZBg

@cde exactly like this...

You might want to explain that a little better in your question then.

@NapoleonWilson thats what all I got?

Pretty sure it's the 1992 movie "Operation Scorpio", also titled "The Scorpion King". Unrelated to the "The Mummy" spinoff movie of the same name featuring the Rock.
Because of the hair of the villain. Very emo. Also, it centers around the (fictional?) scorpion style of kung fu. The protagonist is a comic book artist, covering the drawing part.





Alternative trailer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBDQbo6GUlw

You are 100% sure.. this is that movie... thanks a ton..
